# mysql-connector-c++ - ‘get_driver_instance’ is not a member of ‘sql::mysql’

Tags: c++, mysql, g++

I am a beginner at c++ and figured the only way I am going to learn is to get dirty with some code. I am trying to build a program that connects to a mysql database. I am using g++, on linux. With no ide.

I run "make" and this is my error:

```
hello.cpp:38: error: ‘get_driver_instance’ is not a member of ‘sql::mysql’
make: *** [hello.o] Error 1
```

Here is my code including makefile. Any Help would be great! Thanks in advance

```
###BEGIN hello.cpp###

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

#define EXAMPLE_HOST "localhost"
#define EXAMPLE_USER "root"
#define EXAMPLE_PASS ""
#define EXAMPLE_DB "world"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql::mysql;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{   

    string url(argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : EXAMPLE_HOST);
    const string user(argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : EXAMPLE_USER);
    const string pass(argc >= 4 ? argv[3] : EXAMPLE_PASS);
    const string database(argc >= 5 ? argv[4] : EXAMPLE_DB);

    cout << "Connector/C++ tutorial framework..." << endl;
    cout << endl;


    try { 
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement  *stmt;
        driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute("USE " EXAMPLE_DB);
        stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test");
        stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE test(id INT, label CHAR(1))");
        stmt->execute("INSERT INTO test(id, label) VALUES (1, 'a')");
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        /*
          The MySQL Connector/C++ throws three different exceptions:

          - sql::MethodNotImplementedException (derived from sql::SQLException)
          - sql::InvalidArgumentException (derived from sql::SQLException)
          - sql::SQLException (derived from std::runtime_error)
        */
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        /* Use what() (derived from std::runtime_error) to fetch the error message */
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cout << "Done." << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
###END hello.cpp###

###BEGIN Make File###
SRCS     := hello.cpp
OBJS     := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -pedantic
INCPATHS := -I/home/user/mysql-connector/include/
LIBPATHS := -L/home/user/mysql-connector/lib/ -L/home/user/mysql-connector-c/lib/
LIBS     := -static -lmysqlclient -mysqlcppconn-static
EXE      := MyExecutable



$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(LIBPATHS) $(LIBS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATHS) -c $< -o $@

###End Makefile###
```

Comment: In your next post, highlight code sections then click on "010101".

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here ,  get_driver_instance isn't a member of sql::mysql,so to fix this removing sql::mysql:: and it will work

Change this line

```
driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
```

to this

```
 driver = get_driver_instance();
```

check out the [examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) here

Answer (score 1):

Include : ??

```
#include "mysql_driver.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could successfully compile a program with C++ connector in Ubuntu 12.04 I have installed the connector using this command

```
'apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev'
```

Initially I faced the same problem with "undefined reference to `get_driver_instance' " to solve this I declare my driver instance variable of MySQL_Driver type. For ready reference this type is defined in mysql_driver.h file. Here is the code snippet I used in my program.

```
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
try {     
    driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
}
```

and I compiled the program with -l mysqlcppconn linker option

and don't forget to include this header

```
#include "mysql_driver.h"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The mysql-connector-c page where the OP copy-pasted the code (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-tutorials-background.html) does not list this header file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that function is in the global namespace, don't prepend with `sql::mysql::`

Comment: removed sql::mysql::
...no dice.. Thanks though