# Connecting MySQL from C++: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, mysql

My problem is when I try to connect to MySQL from C++. I have seen page http://www.mysql.com/ and I have read documentation. I downloaded MySQL client with C/C++ connector. I have Windows 7. My configuration in project in Visual Studio 2013 is:

Properities->C/C++->Additional Include Directories:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1.3\include
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.3\include
C:\Users\Darek\Desktop\Anglia\boost_1_55_0
```

Properities->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.3\lib\opt
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1.3\lib
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib
```

Properities->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies:

```
mysqlcppconn-static.lib
libmysql.lib
mysqlcppconn.lib
mysqlclient.lib
```

Properities->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definition:

```
WIN32
NDEBUG
_CONSOLE
_LIB
CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=
```

Code of my project is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn\driver.h>
#include <cppconn\exception.h>
#include <cppconn\resultset.h>
#include <cppconn\statement.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();  //In this line is error
    //con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this project I get error:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
>   sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl
>   sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)"
>   (?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)

Do you know how to solve this error? 
Please help.
Thanks for help.

Comment: is your target platform 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: The answer can be found by searching the web for "mysql get_driver_instance".  That's what I did.

Comment: See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127284/unresolved-symbol-sqlmysqlget-driver-instancevoid

Comment: My platform is 64 bit. Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Matthews for your comment. But I was searching in the web for "mysql get_driver_instance" and another else too but I didn`t find solution of my problem. I found similar problems ,I made steps from them but problem still exists. Maybe I wasn`t searching enough good but... Please for help.

Comment: Target platform is what you build for (not the Windows you are running on). Could you check the project properties to see if your target is 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using `mysqlclient.lib.`

Here are my Preprocessor Definitions:

```
WIN32
WINVER=0x0400
__WXMSW__
_WINDOWS
wxUSE_GUI1
_DEBUG
__WXDEBUG__
_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=
HAVE_INT8_T=1
mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS
```

I'm also using UNICODE setting.

You may have to download the connector source and rebuild it with your settings.

Per my comment above, search the web for "mysql get_driver_instance" and you should be above to confirm my settings above.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2008 on Windows Vista.  The settings work on both platforms.

**Edit 1:**
If you search StackOverflow for "mysql Thomas Matthews" you'll find my postings very similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply. I threw out mysqlclient.lib from Additional Dependencies and changed Preprocessor Definitions on your Definitions but I have still the same error. You said "download connector source", where can I download it? do you mean to install connector c++ from source? From www.mysql.com page? Or another?

Comment: I don't understand people.  I typed "mysql connector c++" into the web search engine (Google) and the first item is "MySql Connector C++ download".  What is the next step?  I clicked on it to get to the download page.  Go to the bottom, in the drop down box for platforms, choose "Source Code".